# Hibernate subtracts one from sequence

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have an existing database schema that I am trying to use with Hibernate 4.1.6. I need to support multiple database versions, including Oracle, so I am using the SequenceStyleGenerator for id generation. I have a sequence created to use with the generator in Oracle.

If the sequence has an existing value (say 2) then I can see that when I call save or update on an entity, Hibernate calls nextval on the sequence to get the next value and gets 3, which is correct. Then, for some reason (in the Hibernate class OptimizerFactory), Hibernate subtracts 1 from the sequence value to get the id to use, which fails due to a unique constraint error - if the nextval is 3, 2 has already been used.

Why is Hibernate subtracting 1 from the sequence to get the value to use for the id, and how do I get it to use the sequence as it is?

Comment: can you add your code what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I was using the pooled optimizer for the SequenceStyleGenerator and the issue has something to do with that. The Hibernate docs say that when using the pooled optimizer, 'we simply store the starting value for the "next group" into the database structure rather than a sequential value in combination with an in-memory grouping algorithm'. So I guess when Hibernate reads the nextval and gets 3, it subtracts one to get the currval which it uses as the starting value for the next group.

I am going to try using "none" for the optimizer ... and also try to find some docs that explain more about the pooled optimizer and how to configure it if applications other than Hibernate are going to be inserting data using the same sequence.